# WebView with QtQuick2

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I can't seem to get a WebView working with QtQuick 2. The error is 
`objc[71279]: Class QNSListener is implemented in both /Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/bearer/libqcorewlanbearer.dylib and /Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/bearer/libqcorewlanbearer_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

I'm compiling on 64-bit Mac OSX running 10.8.4.

The QML is:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0  
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtWebKit 3.0

        WebView {
           id: oauthWeb
           url: "https://www.google.com"
        }
```

I've also included `QT += widgets network webkit webkitwidgets` adn `CONFIG += x86` in the PRO file.

Can't quite work out what is happening. The webview doesn't show at all.